# map and scan array

Tags: ruby

I want to list out all of the strings in an array that include a given keyword.

```
array_name = ["this is california", "hawaii", "washington", "welcome to california"]

a = array_name.map { |s| s.scan(/\b(california)\b/i) }.flatten

# => ["california", "california"]
```

The above will create a new array of strings where each string is "california".  How do I make a new array with the entire original string?

Comment: You may get more attention if you add Ruby to the title or somewhere in your question.  I'm just saying because it wasn't obvious to me at first what language you were using.

Comment: @AlexW: It is tagged "ruby"...

Comment: I realize that. I am merely pointing out that it would get more attention from Ruby gurus if it had Ruby in the title or the body of his question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong method if you're trying to find strings that match, you want `select`:

```
array_name.select { |s| s.match(/\bcalifornia\b/i) }
# ["this is california", "welcome to california"]
```

The [`select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) method:

> Returns an array containing all elements of *enum* for which *block* is not false.

Answer (score 3):

```
array_name.grep /\bcalifornia\b/i
# => ["this is california", "welcome to california"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = array_name.select{|b| b.match /\b(california)\b/i)}
```